# Where can I ask "Where can I find intermediate LaTeX documentation?"

Tags: discussion

I think my question would be off topic on TeX - LaTeX but I'm not sure where to ask it. Where can I ask a question like this:

> I've used LaTeX for several years, but just with basic functionality:
>   writing papers with sections, figures, labels, bibliography, and the
>   occasional table. The problem is that when things get more complicated
>   I have no idea what to do, and I usually end up searching online for
>   several hours to find a "solution", which is usually more like a hack
>   that I don't really understand.
>
> Are there books or tutorials that can help "intermediate users" like
>   me?

Comment: IMO, such a question would be on topic at tex.sx -- it may be a duplicate, though. Have you perused the [tag:documentation] tag?

Comment: I agree with @lockstep. It seems like two similar questions have already been asked: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24105/what-are-good-advanced-latex-books and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51884/free-intermediate-level-documentation

Comment: You're both completely right. @lockstep could you post this as an answer so I can accept it (incorporating doncherry's comments)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IMO, such a question would be on topic at tex.sx -- it may be a duplicate, though. As doncherry has pointed out, the [documentation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/documentation) tag features two questions similar to your proposed one:

- [What are good advanced LaTeX books?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24105/what-are-good-advanced-latex-books)
- [Free intermediate level documentation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51884/free-intermediate-level-documentation)